# Date Picker dates wrongly displaying for Jan/1998

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I am using `mat-datepicker` in my angular version 12 project.
The data picker calender view is displaying wrong dates for the month of Jan-1998.

The 1st of Jan-1998 is starting on Thursday, but it is showing on Sunday. Only 3 days are wrongly displayed.

Here is the form-field

```
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="15" fxFlex.sm="50" class="p-1">
                            <mat-label>Date of birth</mat-label>
                            <input   matInput formControlName="HPM_DOB"  required [matDatepicker]="picker">
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                            <mat-datepicker   #picker></mat-datepicker>
                          </mat-form-field>
```

Am I missing some parameters? Please guide

[image: Please see the attached picture]

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)? I see your mat-datepicker is different with original.

Comment: Did you set the correct date format? The first of February starts on a Sunday. So if your date format is "d/m/yyyy" then it will be displayed correctly. Otherwise you could change to "m/d/yyyy".

Comment: @YongShun you are right, am trying to reproduce.  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fq6etf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) there is no issue with mat-date-picker. I have installed angular2-datetimepicker module. may be that is causing issue,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. Its due to css. In one of my component I am hiding month label of `mat-calander`. After that we removed that  `mat-calander` control and I forgot this css added. It looks like `mat-calander` and `mat-datepicker` are using same css class names.

```
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body-label{
     display:  none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reporduce with `angular2-datetimepicker` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datetimepicker-srthue but I didn't see any issues.

I also tried with `mat-datepicker` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fikhde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts but I could not reproduce the issue.

Anyways, I added locale settings configuration `CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT` to `mat-datepicker` app.module.ts so you could configure this too.

Comment: The mat-date-picker calendar date format is changed once I go to component where  Syncfusion  <ejs-schedule> is defined. Am trying to reproduce in stackblitz, but showing some error.